# Search for a phrase within a field

Tags: solr

I have indexed document in Solr that looks like this:

```
   {
    "name":["Michael"],
    "keywords":["partnerships,business development,marketing,head of product development"],
    "id":"10023e3ze5n8glm6b",
    "city":["sf"],
    "_version_":1549772729479069696},
```

I can search for the document with

```
 "product management"
 "management product"
```

but this doesn't work if I try to search within the `keywords` field,

```
 keywords:"product management"
```

How can I search for a phrase within a field?

Comment: What's the field and type definition for the keywords field? And you don't have the word "management" in your example, so what do you expect to happen exactly? How exactly does it "not work"?

Comment: It wasn't returning result -- 0 doc. It finally figured out that it could be related to my schema or config because a fresh setup does return result as expected.

Comment: Probably didn't commit after reindex then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try

```
fq=keywords:*product management*
```